# How do I get my recorded videos (from camera) off of my iPod Nano 5th gen onto my computer

Tags: video, itunes, ipod

How do I get the videos that I record from the camera from my iPod Nano 5th gen onto my computer?  Is there a way to do it with iTunes, because I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done it, but I found some decent looking instructions [here](http://www.fanpop.com/spots/ipod/forum/post/48968/title/how-copy-ipod-nano-5g-recorded-video-computer):

> **For Windows:**
>
> 1 Connect iPod nano (5th generation)
> to your computer.
>
> 2 In iTunes, click
> iPod in the device list.
>
> 3 Click the
> Summary tab.
>
> 4 If "Enable disk use"
> is not checked, select the checkbox
> and click the Apply button.
>
> You will now be able to copy recorded
> videos to your PC.
>
> Using Windows Explorer or My Computer
> on your PC, the iPod nano will appear
> on the computer as an external disk
> with the same name you gave the iPod
> during the initial setup in iTunes.
>
> The DCIM folder on iPod nano stores
> your recorded video. You can copy this
> folder to your computer so that you
> can view the video on your PC, or to
> back up the video files.
>
> Once the recorded video is copied to
> your PC, double-click on the file to
> watch the video using QuickTime or
> Windows Media Player. See the
> documentation that came with your
> computer for assistance.
>
> **For Mac: (using iPhoto)**
>
> To copy your recorded video from your
> iPod nano to iPhoto, you first need to
> make sure the "Enable disk use"
> checkbox is selected for your iPod
> within iTunes.
>
> 1 Connect your iPod to your computer.
>
> 2 Open iTunes (version 9 or later).
>
> 3 Select your iPod in the Source pane.
>
> 4 Select the Summary tab.
>
> 5 Enable disk use and select the Apply button.
>
> **Import your recorded videos from iPod nano (5th generation) to iPhoto**
>
> 1 Open the iPhoto application if it
> doesn't open automatically.
>
> 2 Click iPod in the iPhoto device list.
>
> 3 Select the video or videos
> to import. Click Import Selected or
> Import All.
>
> 4 After the video or
> videos have been imported into iPhoto,
> choose either Delete Photos or Keep
> Photos when prompted to "Delete Photos
> on Your Camera."  Your recorded video
> or videos will appear in your iPhoto
> Library under the section for Events
> and Photos and in the Recent category
> for Last Import.
>
> To watch the video in iPhoto,
> double-click the recorded video.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. That did. I figured iTunes would have a built in feature to handle this, but the enable disk use thing makes sense too.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked. :)